# How to insert a wide table in a post?

Tags: support, editor, formatting

How can I insert a 10 column table in cleaner format in a Stack Overflow question?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of an inline 12-column table using a pair of `<b> </b>` tags and a pair of `<pre> </pre>` tags to format the text.

```
flights
#         year month day dep_delay arr_delay carrier origin dest air_time distance hour
#      1: 2014     1   1        14        13      AA    JFK  LAX      359     2475    9
#      2: 2014     1   1        -3        13      AA    JFK  LAX      363     2475   11
#      3: 2014     1   1         2         9      AA    JFK  LAX      351     2475   19
#      4: 2014     1   1        -8       -26      AA    LGA  PBI      157     1035    7
#      5: 2014     1   1         2         1      AA    JFK  LAX      350     2475   13
#     ---                                                                              
# 253312: 2014    10  31         1       -30      UA    LGA  IAH      201     1416   14
# 253313: 2014    10  31        -5       -14      UA    EWR  IAH      189     1400    8
# 253314: 2014    10  31        -8        16      MQ    LGA  RDU       83      431   11
# 253315: 2014    10  31        -4        15      MQ    LGA  DTW       75      502   11
# 253316: 2014    10  31        -5         1      MQ    LGA  SDF      110      659    8
```

Comment: You could use something like [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) to make the job easier.